# r: arc length of a plotted line?

Tags: r, calculus

Can r do arc lengths of plots?

Say I have

```
library("DiagTest3Grp", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")

data <- c(34,46,47,48,52,53,55,56,56,56,57,58,59,59,68)
bw <- BW.ref(data)
x0 <- seq(0, 100, .1) 
KS.cdfvec <- Vectorize(KernelSmoothing.cdf, vectorize.args = "c0")
x0.cdf <- KS.cdfvec(xx = data, c0 = x0, bw = bw)
plot(x0, x0.cdf, type = "l")
```

Produces graph

[image]

Could I derive the arc length of the plotted line given any x (say arc length is measured from the left), or given any two x's?

Comment: `density(data)['x']` and `density(data)['y']` give you the x and y coordinates of each point the line goes through. You might be able to do something with that

Comment: that gives me an idea, I can do pythagorean theorem on a bunch of x,y's using approx(y=x0, x=x0.cdf, xout=0.8)